# Hooking Django (DRF) to an existing database

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I think I am looking for as much advise as possible.

I have a project that I have inherited. The codebase is absolutely awful. I have a Django project, within this a React app. There's all manner of proxies between to fetch from the API to deliver up content.

However, I want to start to re-write the API, as it is awfully put together. Zero documentation.

To re-write the API, I would like take a copy of the exisiting database - and then work with this to write a more consistent API.

What would be your advise/steps/method to achieve this, and what should I look out for when doing this?

N.B. The database is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

For this Django itself has the [`inspectdb` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/).

It will inspect all tables, fields, and foreign-key relations and then create unmanaged models for you. You can fix them manually with (perhaps) missing foreign-keys and then use them in django-rest-framework.